# Displaying the value from Get-Credentials

Tags: powershell, credentials

I thought this would be simple but I can't seem to display a value correctly.
In a Powershell script I use the Get-Credentials prompt to allow someone to enter their elevated account details to perform user creation in AD and Exchange.
I write a log out for each run of the script with date and name information.  One of the fields I was trying to capture was the username of the person entered at the credentials stage.

Here is what I am using

```
$CurrentUser = Get-Credential
Add-Content $outputfile "Running as $CurrentUser.UserName"
```

and I am getting this line out in the log

Running as System.Management.Automation.PSCredential.UserName

Can someone let me know what I should be putting there in order to display the user name entered at the prompt.

Many thanks

S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to put it in a [sub-expression](https://www.pdq.com/blog/using-subexpressions-within-strings/) to have it output the string from the `.UserName` property.

```
# Subexpression:
Add-Content $outputfile "Running as $($CurrentUser.UserName)"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$CurrentUser = Get-Credential
Add-Content $outputfile ("Running as " + $CurrentUser.UserName)
```

You shouldn't put your command in a string

Comment: You need to surround `"Running as " + $CurrentUser.UserName` with `()` for it to be passed as one parameter (and not throw an error).

Comment: ah right forgot about it I only tested the String. Thanks for the reminder.